# Align top of div to bottom of it's parent

Tags: jquery, html, css-animations

Current site:
http://goo.gl/SA2ajX

I have this size changing header (uses `CSS3` animations and `jQuery`) with a bunch of `li` tags in it.

When I hover over one of those `li` elements, I want a secondary header to drop below the original one (which contains some links). When I add the second `div`, how can I align it directly underneath the main `div` without regardless of the size?

Edit: if you resize the browser window, the header changes it's size. That is why I'm having trouble, I can't simply change around the CSS to make it fit because it would be different on another screen.

Comment: Possibly you could offset it the same way as you have done with the image. Instead of having an image though just use another element and scale it horizontally?

Comment: I would do that, but the the header size is responsive to the width of the page, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to a simple drop down menu.

```css
.list
{
  width:12.5%;
 }

#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px;
  width:100%;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 //float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item list"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul >
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I was wondering how you could make easy drop down menus like that. But what I'd rather have is a horizontal list that fills the width of the page instead of a tiny container box

Comment: Just updated the code snippet. Basically, what I did was, give a class name to all the outer `li`s (ex. `menu 1`...) Then I gave the width of 12.5%. The trick to make it expand, is to give it a percentage %, instead of px.